# Laravel - Undefined property in array

Tags: arrays, variables, laravel

I cant figure out why, but I can var_dump($cPage) and get the complete array, but I can't access my variable in the view. {{ $cPage->code }} allways gets me an "Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$code" error. Can anyone explain me why?

Controller:

```
public function getPages($lang, $slug)
{

    $cPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
            ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
            ->where('code', '=', $lang)
            ->get();

    $mainPages = Page::where('parent_id', null)
                ->get();

    $allPages = $this->getAllPages($mainPages);

    return View::make('index')
    ->with('cPage', $cPage)
    ->with('mainPages', $mainPages)
    ->with('allPages', $allPages);

}
```

View

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <button type="submit" class="btn dropdown-toggle icon-white" data-toggle="dropdown"> {{ $cPage->code }} <b class="caret"></b></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
      <li><a href="#">Português</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`var_dump($cPage)`

> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["parent_id"]=>
>   NULL ["lang_parent_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["translate_parent_id"]=> NULL
>   ["title"]=> string(8) "Clientes" ["slug"]=> string(8) "clientes"
>   ["sort"]=> NULL ["name"]=> string(10) "PortuguÃªs" ["code"]=>
>   string(2) "pt" } }

Comment: Try ->first() instead of get

Comment: Thanks, it worked with ->first(). Can you offer me an explanation for this?

Comment: Your query potentially returns multiple results so get returns a collection (even if its just one result). First limits the query to one result and returns that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use loop in your view, or if you expect only one result, you can change `get` into `first`:

```
$cPage = Page::join('langs', 'langs.id', '=', 'pages.lang_parent_id')
        ->where('slug', '=', $slug)
        ->where('code', '=', $lang)
        ->first();
```